# Перебор многомерного массива. Сортировка ключей. Построение нового массива

Tags: php, массивы

Из базы данных приходит массив с именем директории и названием файла, который
принадлежит конкретной директории. Задача сформировать новый массив, в котором не будет
повторяющихся ключей и файлы будут находится в той директории, которой принадлежат. Вот, что
приходит:

```php
$array = [
    0 => [
              "directory" => "film",
              "name" => "955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db867.png"
         ],
    1 => [
              "directory" => "film",
              "name" => "955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db868.png"
         ],
    2 => [
              "directory" => "video",
              "name" => "955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db869.png"
         ], 
    3 => [
              "directory" => "img",
              "name" => "955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db868.png"
         ], 
    4 => [
              "directory" => "img",
              "name" => "955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db869.png"
         ]
];
```

Из этого нужно сделать:

```php
$array = [
    0 => [
              "directory" => "film",
              "name" => ["955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db867.png", "955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db869.png"]
         ],
    1 => [
              "directory" => "video",
              "name" => ["955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db869.png"]
         ],
    2 => [
              "directory" => "img",
              "name" => ["955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db868.png", "955898ab4e7edd4d6a159acd4a2db869.png"]
         ],
];
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с построением массива. Не могу понять как сконструировать
его, убрав лишние ключи и сформировать имена файлов исходя из принадлежности к директориям.

Comment: заводите массив, где директория будет ключ. Идете по исходному. Берете директорию, смотрите есть ли она в этом новом. Если нет - создаете пункт, `$result[] = ['directory` => ..., 'name' => []]`. И потом просто пихаете в name текущее значение. В конце ключи скинуть можно.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: $newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $newArray[$item['directory']][] = $item['name'];

}

Comment: Или использовать правильный вывод из базы данных:  $response = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|\PDO::FETCH_GROUP);